# How can I change key bindings in MAMP using "and"/"not" logic?

Tags: key-binding, emulator

How can I use `and` `not` logic in mame hotkeys? I figured out how to set `or`, by just setting new and new hotkeys. But `and` and `not`?

Also, where the hotkeys are stored, how to backup them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a keybinding with `AND`, press enter, then press both keys you want to set. It will then be presented as `KEY1 KEY2`.

To make a keybinding with `OR`, press enter, press the key you want to bind and allow it to set. Press enter again and press the second key. It will present as `KEY1 OR KEY2`

To make a keybinding with `NOT`, press enter, press the key you want to bind then press the next key twice quickly. It will present as `KEY1 NOT KEY2`

The keybindings are stored in the cfg directory in a file named `default.cfg`.